# Linux shell, C programming, script execution, syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: c, linux, bash, syntax-error

I tried to execute script within C program. I tried:

```
system("/home/olaudix/weather.sh") 

system("sh /home/olaudix/weather.sh")

execvp("/home/olaudix/weather.sh")
```

but all of them throw

> syntax error: "(" unexpected at line 1.

Scripts starts with `function getData() {` but it runs fine when executed in terminal.

Comment: you could try: `sh -c`

Comment: Line 1? You're missing a `#!` line. Also, if you want to be compatible with sh, it should be `getData() {` (without `function`).

Comment: What I need to make in C is "shell" program that can execute scripts and programs after user gives relative or absolute path to said scripts. I can't edit the scripts themselves and I think that if it works in terminal i have to make it work in my program.

Answer (score 4):

The *[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))* (i.e.: `#!`) at the very beginning of the scripts is missing. You need it in order to specify the corresponding interpreter (`bash` in this case), i.e.:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: What I need to make in C is "shell" program that can execute scripts and programs after user gives relative or absolute path to said scripts. I can't edit the scripts themselves and I think that if it works in terminal i have to make it work in my program.

Comment: Then, you can call `bash` with the script to run as an argument as part of `system()` (i.e.: `bash -c "command-to-run"`).

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to source the shell script in the `system` command. Below is an example

```
$ cat 48465591.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
system(". ./myshellscript.sh"); // Note the '.' which stands for sourcing
return 0;
}
$ cat myshellscript.sh
printhello()
{
echo "Hello";
}
```